# How to develop the smaller muscles of the back?

Tags: muscle, bodybuilding, muscle-gain, muscle-groups, muscle-growth

Whenever we see a muscular back,we think of the lats, middle back and the lower.But there are many smaller muscles which make an asthetic back.Any exercise to isolate those smaller muscle groups?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are tons.  Two huge ones.

- Scapular Retraction (Rhomboids, Lower Trap)
- Shoulder External Rotation (Infraspinatus, Teres Minor)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQqgf8kB6R8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvW1tOPwTBM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1k3RStA0ec8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-7ZWPCWv0U